# How to automatically export dashboard in databricks jobs

Tags: python, api, databricks

I have a notebook in databricks that I put into a job to run every day at specific time, and I've also created dashboard from this notebook, how can I have the dashboard results exported automatically every time the job runs? I'm aware of the Jobs API, but I can't figure out the right command to do this. Right now I'm using the python package databricks-api (https://pypi.org/project/databricks-api/) to connect to databricks. My ultimate goal is to automate the process of running the notebook, create dashboard, and then save the results.

Comment: So once you have ran a job to generate a dashboard report, you will get a run id
pass this run if to the jobs api `DatabricksAPI.jobs.export_run(
    run_id,
    views_to_export=None,
    headers=None,
)`

Comment: How do you go about getting a run_id if the cluster is offline and there are no jobs listed in the UI or by calling the API [2.0/jobs/runs/list](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-list)? The dashboard is fully viewable so running a job shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out? I have the same question. This won't be the full answer, but to export just the notebook use the API as demonstrated at at these two links:

[1](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#export)
[2](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/examples.html#export-a-notebook-or-folder)

This curl command will export a notebook as HTML. What it doesn't do is clearly present the dashboard cleanly, without code, as is so easily done via the Databricks UI:

```
curl -n -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d @- https://<mysite>.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/workspace/export <<JSON
{
  "path": "/Users/my@login.com/notebook_001",
  "format": "HTML"
}
JSON
```

or to download an html file manually:

```
curl -n -o example.html "https://<yoursite>.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/workspace/export?format=HTML&direct_download=true&path=/Users/you@yourlogin.com/notebookname_001"
```

You're probably well beyond this, but it assumes a .netrc and token per this [article](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html).

[I would be happy to have edits showing how this process could be changed to export the HTML without code, or better yet in the dashboard view. I too have been over the Jobs [API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-export) and do not see how it's relevant to an already-run notebook which does not require an online cluster to view the dashboard.]